# Database monitoring application's architecture

Tags: c#, winforms, architecture, windows-services

I've been given a task to develop an application for monitoring/backuping databases on our servers.

the application should do this things

- backup and copy the backup at given time to a given place(the user can change the time and the place)
- send email notifications about the finished backups at given time, if an error occured, report the details
- all the backup parameters should be editable
- read the database credentials from a given place

So I was thinking of a windows service which would be configurable by a windows forms application. Am I going the right direction here ?

Comment: I'm betting there are a ton of third party products built exactly for this purpose, why reinvent the wheel? Not to mention some database products have this built in.

Comment: Can you please point me to some ?

Comment: @user49126 if you tell me which databases you use, I can provide some names in my answer.

Comment: We use the Oracle database

Comment: @user49126 I've added an option to my answer which might be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of products which are designed to do this. It's easier and probably way cheaper to get an existing product (with decent support) than to develop something yourself, test it, troubleshoot it etc etc.
Oracle has implemented a backup and restore function for its databases, see [Introduction to Backup and Recovery](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmintro.htm).

Also, IIRC a Windows Service is designed not to communicate with forms (or the other way around), so your suggestion probably wouldn't work as you'd expect. [MSDN: Interactive Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Note the following text:

> Services cannot directly interact with a user as of Windows Vista. Therefore, the techniques mentioned in the section titled Using an Interactive Service should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without 3rd part software. Let say each RDBMS comes with some set of tools ie. command line tools. One of them is (can be?) backup/restore. Now what you can do:

1. write a batch file to do the job
2. create a task for windows task scheduler which will run that batch (and yes, you can send email via task scheduler)